# Safari update message on my Mac, why is it there for four days?

Tags: safari

When I click on Safari I get message telling me:

> "Safari is being updated... Safari can not be opened while it is being updated"

When will updating Safari be finished on my computer? I need to use it and it has been updating for four days now. What do I do now to use Safari?

Comment: Who is you? Have you already restarted your Mac? Please provide us additional information, like the Mac you are using e.g.: MBP 13'' mid 2014 and the OS X version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

This will work with any stuck update from the app store, btw, just change the names of the stuff to delete.

First thing to try: clear the app store updates folder at Macintosh HD/Library/Updates

Second thing to try: Open Terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal) and paste this: `open $TMPDIR../C` and in there, delete anything that has the name com.apple.appstore then do the same in Terminal with this command: `open $TMPDIR../T`

Third thing to try: Open Disk Utility (Same place as Terminal), select your hard drive and run Fix Permissions.

One of those should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit on that, I can see how mine would be confusing.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the update died prematurely and didn't clean up, so the system thinks it's still being updated. After completing the update, the locks will be cleaned up and you'll be able to open Safari again.  From the Terminal, execute:

```
open /Library/Updates/*/ApplicationLoader.pkg
```

That should pop open a window with the usual installer.  Go through the motions to install the package.  Once it's done, you should be able to run Safari.

[Here](http://appletoolbox.com/forums/topic/cant-use-safari-says-safari-updated-cannot-opened-days/#post-29280)'s where I got the solution myself.